# As "postscript" is one word, why do some abbreviate it as "p.s."?

Tags: etymology, abbreviations, latin, postscript

'Postscript' is a single word in modern English, and [Dictionary.com states](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/postscript) that it's even based on a *single* Latin word, *postscrīptum*.  So, why do some abbreviate it to *p.s.* (or *P.S.*), as on [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_abbreviations)? Is it OK to abbreviate it as *ps.*?

Update: It seems Dictionary.com may have been wrong with its etymological explanation of the modern English word.  Nevertheless, given that the modern English 'postscript' *is* one single word, shouldn't the abbreviation be able to be updated?

Comment: Because abbreviating it as “P” wouldn't be very clear, would it?

Comment: Nope, but I like *ps.* ... then again, I like *eg.* and *ie.* too.

Comment: Dictionary.com is clearly wrong. Anyway, your question about its spelling is related to [Punctuation after “P.S.”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19311/punctuation-after-p-s)

Comment: @F'x: "Because abbreviating it as “P” wouldn't be very clear, would it?" That's why it's not even under consideration at all. (Abbreviations are not limited to single letters, of course.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that Dictionary.com might have made a mistake in connecting the two words. Both Etymonline.com and Wikipedia agree on it being separate:

> [Etymonline.com:](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=postscript&searchmode=none) 1520s, from L. post scriptum "written after," from neuter pp
>
> [Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postscript) The term comes from the Latin post scriptum, an expression meaning "written after"

Thus, the explanation for why it's written *P.S.* is probably because it came from two separate Latin words.

Comment: But is it now legitimate to say *ps.* instead?

Comment: No, as everyone still writes it as "p.s." or "P.S.", haven't heard of "ps." yet

Comment: @Thursagen: It's not *probably*, but the exact reason why it's written P.S., because they are 2 words. :)

Comment: @Jez: P.S. is not only used in English. Also German uses it as P.S., while PS stands for "Pferdestärke" — "Horsepower"

Comment: Do we have precedent in English for putting a period after contracted abbreviations? Reading "ps." I would assume the word began ps... and interpret the abbreviation as psychology or something. If we were to recognize the single word nature it would just be ps, no period.

Answer (score 7):

Dictionary.com is wrong here. The correct Latin origin is *post scriptum*, literally "after the written", definitely 2 words. I've had Latin in school.

Comment: Short and clear, and I agree with you. +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

The word *postscript* may be based on a single latin word (the jury seems to be out on that one...), but it's not the english word *postscript* that you use for a postscript in a letter (or the single latin word that it might be based on), it's the latin term *post scriptum*, which is two words.